# Custom message boxes in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I really like the look/behavior of window created by MessageBox.Show. How can I create one from scratch so that I can add other stuff like a textbox?

Answer (score 3):

There's a good [article here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx) on creating your own version, which is now on [CodePlex](http://wpassets.codeplex.com/). There various customizable MessageBoxes in the [Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/). If you want to do it all on your own, [this guide](http://cloudstore.blogspot.com/2011/01/customizing-messagebox-on-windows-phone.html) might help as well.

Comment: http://cloudstore.blogspot.com/2011/01/customizing-messagebox-on-windows-phone.html (your 3rd link) matches the look the closest, and has a similar animation. However, I've had issues with it in a situation where the MessageBox could pop up more than once before the animation can complete. (say, showing a MessageBox on a Button Click, or the hardware back-button)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `MessageBox`, you could try using a `Popup`.

But, you'll have to manually disable the contols on the screen when the popup is open (`MessageBox` does this automatically for you). Also, you'll have to override the back button behaviour so that back button closes the `Popup` if it is open. This is also automatically done by a `MessageBox`.

Comment: That seems reasonable. I'll just have to put in a full-screen canvas to block interaction with the background.

Answer (score 0):

In Mix11, Laurent Bugnion talked about Mvvm. In hist samples, there is a sample including the implement of Custom MessageBox. u can download the sourcecode from [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2011/04/13/deep-dive-mvvm-samples-mix11-deepdivemvvm.aspx) and check the "03 JsonDemo - WP7 DialogService " sample.

Hope this help u.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [custom implementation](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2011/11/13/Creating-a-Custom-MessageBox-for-Windows-Phone-Applications.aspx). Looks and behaves just like the out of the box MessageBox and is easy to use. I've used it in two of my phone apps.

Answer (score 0):

Add references to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` and `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices` and then you can do the following:

```
Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Title",
                          "Text",
                          new List<String> { "Answer 1", "Answer 2" },
                          0, // Focus button
                          MessageBoxIcon.Alert,
                          asyncResult =>
                          {
                              int? response = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(asyncResult);
                              if(response == null)
                              {
                                  // Back button pressed
                              }
                              else if(response == 0)
                              {
                                  // "Answer 1" pressed
                              }
                              else if(response == 1)
                              {
                                  // "Answer 2" pressed
                              }
                          },
                          null);
```

I have tested this with Windows Phone 7 and it appears to work.

Comment: Note: It appears that you can only provide 1 or 2 strings in the List.